# Button to add widgets , in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

In Tkinter, how would look like the code of button that adds a widget when clicked, infinitely if necessary?

Thanks and sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it could look something like this (it could look like a lot of different things):

```
import Tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
count = 0
def add_line():
    global count
    count += 1
    tk.Label(text='Label %d' % count).pack()
tk.Button(root, text="Hello World", command=add_line).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a more "classy" version:

```
from Tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.number = 0
        self.widgets = []
        self.grid()
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.cloneButton = Button ( self, text='Clone', command=self.clone)
        self.cloneButton.grid()

    def clone(self):
        widget = Label(self, text='label #%s' % self.number)
        widget.grid()
        self.widgets.append(widget)
        self.number += 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Application()
    app.master.title("Sample application")
    app.mainloop()
```

[image]

Note you keep your widgets in self.widgets list, so you can recall them and modify them if you like.

Comment: How I would add new widgets in a TopLevel?